# Regex to find special characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I can use

```
var regex = /[$&+,:;=?@#|]/;

if(elem.match(regex)) { // do something 
}
```

to find whether there is any special characters in string in Javascript.

How can I use the similar regular expression in Java?

I have tried:

```
str.match("\\="); // return false
```

For example:

```
String str = "123=456";
```

I tried to detect "=" in str.

That did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A simple Google search for "java regex" and you could have found: [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) all on your own!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=?@#|]");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("123=456");
if (matcher.find()){
    // Do something
}
```

EDIT: `matches()` checks all the string and `find()` finds it in any part of the string.

A link: [`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

Comment: For his particular regex, the pattern would be created with `Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=?@#|]")` without the slashes.

Comment: I tried your code. It can not work :(

Comment: sorry, my fault ....
Because I used JSP, I forgot to refresh my server......

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). 
Read the Javadocs for supported syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String.matches(String regex);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's some sample code:

```
import java.lang.Scanner;
/*setup everything here, you just need that import*/
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//ask for input
String str = input.next();
if(str.contains(/*char1*/) || str.contains(/*char2*/) || /*continue the pattern, 1 for every character*/)
{
    //event if it contains one
}
else
{
    //event if it does not contain any
}
```

an alternatve:

```
import java.lang.Scanner;
/*put the program parts here*/
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = input.next();
List<char> chars = Arrays.asList(/*put chars here, seperated with commas*/);
for(int x = 0; x < chars.size();x++)
{
    if(str.contains(chars[x]))
    {
        //event if it contains one
    }
    else
    {
        //event if it does not contain one
    }
}
//resume program
```

these code snippets will work, assuming everything is imported correctly.

Comment: would someone explain why they downvoted my answer? it submitted before I had finished typing, and I edited it to contain the rest of the information.

Comment: This will only check if all the characters are in a `sequence` and not a single `char` as in the case of his`regex`. -1

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati could you explain? the first one checks if one or more of the characters are in the string, the second one does it one at a time using a for loop based off the size of a list that contains the special characters.

Comment: This type of check is `limited` to checking for a `CharSequence` and this is why `regex` is implemented

Comment: @Grammer: Regular expressions are a very powerful tool, developed over years. Reinventing it in a bad way is not a good solution.